# Rails5: filtering with sunspot_solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I have a search implemented with the gem sunspot_solr. I would like to add links in the search results to be able to filter the search by alphabetical order and other parameters.
my controller is

```
class SearchController < SuperSiteController
  def index
    @sunspot_search = Sunspot.search User, Post do |query| 
      query.keywords @search_query
      query.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
    end

    @posts = @sunspot_search.results

  end
```

I wish I could filter for older, recent, and alphabetical order within your search has already been completed. I did not find anything in the documentation about this.

Has anyone worked with this type of search before, and if so, do you know the best practice for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you aim to order results based on a property (data field) of documents.
For example, to sort the results of `Post` model by `created_at`, you have to add this field to the index definition in `app/models/post.rb` as below:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    searchable do
        ...
        time :created_at
        ...
    end
end
```

And then in you `SearchController` sort the result as below:

```
class SearchController < SuperSiteController
  def index
    Post.search do
      fulltext @search_query
      paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
      order_by :created_at, :desc #:desc for descending, :asc for ascending
    end

    @posts = @sunspot_search.results

  end
```

In order to order results alphabetically you just have to add the field to you index definition as what mentioned above with text function instead of time and use `order_by` in `SearchController`.